# cant get my navigation to work right

Tags: css

hey guys Im new to web design but cant get my navigation to align across the top or remove the  bullets from the li. I had it worked out but it started interferring with the rest of the page so I reworked it some and cant get it to work now. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
.menuitem {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 240px;
}

#navigation {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #0b61a4;
    font-size: 18pt;
}

nav a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #CED9D9;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}

nav a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}

nav a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>                 
    <li><a href="index.html" class="menuitem">Home</a></li>                 
    <li><a href="pharmacy_solutions" class="menuitem">Pharmacy Solutions</a></li>                 
    <li><a href="about_us.html" class="menuitem">About Us</a></li>                 
    <li><a href="contact_us.html" class="menuitem">Contact Us</a></li>             
  </ul>         
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML markup?

Comment: @Barbara Laird here is the code around the navigation sorry about it being hard to read, couldn't get it to format right` <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="menuitem">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="pharmacy_solutions" class="menuitem">Pharmacy Solutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="about_us.html" class="menuitem">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact_us.html" class="menuitem">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ACQ27/2/

```
#navigation {
    width: 1040px;
    background-color: #0b61a4;
    font-size: 18pt;
}

#navigation ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
     display:inline-block;
}
#navigation ul li {
     display:inline-block;
     width: 240px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}

#navigation ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover {
    color: #CED9D9;

}
```

Comment: I'll have to play with it some, to make it look right, but that got it to start the formatting for me. Thanks!!!

Comment: had to tweek it a little but the code now works like I want it, Thank you again!